# ld: framework not found Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I've spent few days trying to solve this issue and I am running out of ideas now.

I have:
Xcode v8.2.1
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
cocoapods-1.2.0

I am creating new Xcode project (Single View Application), chose clean and build - everything works like a charm.

After pod init in root project path I am editing my Podfile as below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

  # Pods for test

end
```

now when I try to clean and rebuild app I am getting build error, as per below:

```
d /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Dawid/xCode/test
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -filelist /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.swiftmodule -framework Alamofire -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app.xcent -framework Pods_test -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Dawid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-auxygswgvxhnqfamjqqncqxaieqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire'
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to edit Framework Search Paths to $(inherited) , clean projects, reopen Xcode, try fresh copy, download previous version of Alamofire and basically everything which I found on the net but nothing worked so far.

EDIT:
Overview printscreen added

EDIT 2: 
After @Jagdeep suggestion, now I have different errors (print screen attached):
[image]

[image: project tree]

Comment: Could you supply a screenshot of your Xcode project overview screen please? The one you get where you click the blue xcode project in the left pane.

Comment: ok, already added

Comment: Oh wow, thanks but I hate to be a pain! Can you expand the left pane of that view via the button in the top left? The info I was looking for is there! I have a suspicion I know what the issue is but want to confirm...

Answer (score 4):

Trying going to your

`Target>Build Setting>Build Active Architecture Only`

set it

- **Yes** for **Debug**
- **No** for **Release**

make **sure** you have **same config for all target**
Also in your

```
Pods>Build Setting>Build Active Architecture Only
```

keep the **same values**.

Clean and build
hope it works

Comment: check for  framework under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> and select alamofire.framework.

Comment: make sure you open the workspace rather than the project file
secondly try install pod and update pod

Comment: I was already opening workspace however it looks like pod update did the job. One more question - I am getting warning now "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Dawid/xCode/test/build/Debug-iphoneos'" any idea why?

Comment: Opening the project file instead of the workspace was my problem. Thanks @Jagdeep

Answer (score 1):

You will get this important message, when you do `pod install` the first time:

`` [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Project.xcworkspace` for this project from now on. ``

That means you have yo quit Xcode, then open the Project.xcworkspace file every time when you want to work on your project.